# Does a transistor amplifier produce negative voltage?

Tags: transistors, amplifier

So I've recently started electroncis and bought this course on udemy ("Electricity and electronics - Robotics by Ian Juby") and I'm slightly confused as to how the circuit that I've attached to this post works.[image: Inverting Transistor Amplifier]

An AC signal is applied to the transistor base which turns on and off the transistor. I understand how that works. What I don't understand is that the instructor is saying that the voltage on the output swings negative with the AC signal. But surely the output would only go to 0V as the input voltage is DC from collector to emitter and the transistor is on (It's an inverting amplifier) and therefore the resistance is extremely low and therefore the voltage divider output would be 0 and not go negative?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you think its negative because the gain is -10?   That means its inverted, not a  negative voltage.   I.e  you're right, the output doesn't go below ground.

Comment: This simple circuit is a common emitter amplifier, which is an inverter, but output voltage remains positive. A positive voltage on the microphone becomes some low voltage near 0V on the output while a negative voltage on the microphone is amplified to an high level, closer to the 10V power supply

Comment: "Swings negative" is another way of saying "changes from a high positive voltage to a lower voltage", or "moves in the negative direction".  It doesn't necessarily mean "goes to a negative voltage".

Answer (score 3):

No, the output could never go negative in this circuit, it is relatively simple to understand why.

The best mental model of how transistors work that I've seen comes from "The Art of Electronics". Imagine a little person sitting inside the transistor, there is a diode connected from the base to the emitter with an ammeter hooked to it, and there is a variable resistor connected between the emitter and the collector which the little man controls. Depending on what value he sees on the ammeter he will adjust the variable resistor accordingly (the exact relationship isn't important for this question).

As such if you imagine the transistor in this circuit as basically a diode and a variable resistor you can quickly see that no matter what value the resistor could possibly be at the voltage presented could never go outside of the voltage of the rails themselves. You have a positive rail and 0V rail. As such you know it is guaranteed your voltage can never go negative.

Even if we assume the base could go negative somehow that still wouldn't cause the output to go negative. If the base goes negative than the diode becomes reverse biased and will not conduct. As such the transistor wont engage and the virtual variable resistor between collector and emitter will remain high. so your output voltage would still be positive.

Comment: Exactly! "Voltage controlled resistor" is the most intuitive notion about the transistor that gives a chance to understand/explain what it does in the circuit. It is a passive element and the only thing it can do is to dissipate power in a form of heat. Indeed, the transistor is a "nonlinear resistor" but this is not essential in the case. Eventually, when the collector voltage is zero, it has used up all its resistance and its collector voltage could "go down" below zero only if its resistance becomes negative (if there were a negative voltage source inside it... as I joke with my students:-)

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Close, a transistor is a "Current controlled resistor", however a FET is a "Voltage controlled resistor", the difference is significant.

But yea otherwise spot on, there is no such thing as a negative resistor and thus no way the voltage could go negative.

Comment: Jeffrey Phillips Freeman, I agree with you. It is convenient to think of BJT as of a current-controlled device but they say that actually it is voltage-controlled. But this is also not essential in the case since we are interested in the output circuit. Really, there is no negative resistor as an element but there are circuits acting as a negative resistor (NIC). Of course, it was only joke... I thank you for the intuitive answer; this is a support for this idea that meets fierce opposition here...

Comment: yea not particularly relevant here, I agree. but it is really only voltage controlled when you look at it at the atomic level. It is the voltage potential across the junction that effects the depletion zone. So as long as you are operating it below its forward voltage (which means a few millivolts) then what you say is true. But in practice it will just confuse people. What your really getting at is that both are technically voltage controlled but a BJT is a low impedance input with a very small voltage range, a FET is a high impedance with a large voltage range.

Comment: Yes... it is exactly what I think. Figuratively speaking, the base-emitter junction acts as a "piece of wire" (an "ideal current load" with zero resistance) and the gate-source part of a FET acts as "nothing" (an open circuit or "ideal voltage load" with infinite high resistance). Regarding the output voltage... It can "go down" by adding another but negative power supply and another but p-n-p transistor connected in a push-pull configuration (the clever complementary idea). I think it would be interesting for you to visit Circuit Idea wikibook - a book about the great ideas behind circuits...

Answer (score 2):

If the transistor is fully saturated on, the output may fall to 0.2 V, while the input remains at 0.7 V. Thus, the output can be at −0.5 V *relative to the input*. This may be what they are actually saying? But its absolute value can never go below 0 V unless you have reactive components in the output circuit.

Comment: The "virtual ground" at the base is "lifted" with 0.7 V (see my answer).

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Your point being?

Comment: Only some observations... I think this transistor stage resembles an op-amp inverting amplifier. The base is biased with 0.7 V and acts as a "lifted virtual ground". The input and output voltages "pull" it in opposite directions through the resistors 1 k and 10 k; so it stays "immovable". But there is a limitation - the input voltage can be only negative since the output voltage is always positive. I think there is something wrong with this circuit...

Comment: Guy Inchbald, I think this circuit is still an analog amplifier.  First, the transistor is "self-biased" by the  negative feedback introduced by the voltage divider connected between the collector and ground (like in the circuit of a "Vbe multiplier"). Then, it is biased by the top resistor in the middle that is connected to Vcc. In my opinion, it can be omitted (four resistors to one point are too many:) I am not so interested in the specific circuit solution but rather in the fundamental ideas behind it. My pursuit is to collect circuit ideas and classify them in a hierarchical system.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't looking closely enough. I deleted my comment. Still looks OK to me, though. But as with all biploar types, the 0.7 V  is set by the forward bias voltage of the base-emitter junction. The resistors set a bias *current*, it's not like a FET.

Comment: Guy Inchbald, Let me say a few more words because the topic is very interesting... and here is rarely a benevolent interlocutor like you to have a discussion. Actually, the four resistors connected with one of their ends to the base form a 4-input resistor summing circuit. It sums (with its weighted inputs) Vin + Vc + Vcc + Vground. Its output is the base current or, if you prefer, the base voltage... and it is kept around 0.7 V by the negative feedback. I agree that the resistors set the current here.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist That is incorrect. It is kept at 0.7 V by the forward bias voltage across the base-emitter junction. It would remain at 0.7 V if the feedback resistor were open-circuited. Unless and until you can understand bipolar transistors better, there is little point in pursuing this issue.

Comment: I wonder what is incorrect... I mean a transistor with collector resistor and voltage divider (upper R1 and bottom R2) between the collector and base (i.e., a "rubber Zener diode"). Imagine there is no Vcc; so there is no Vbe... no currents... no voltages... When you turn on the power supply, the transistor is off. The collector voltage begins increasing but there is no collector current... and when it reaches Vbe.(1 + R1/R2), the transistor begins conducting. The collector current begins increasing. The collector voltage and, accordingly, the Vbe decrease... so the equilibrium is reached...

Comment: ... Vbe is around 0.7 V. R1 and R2 are chosen so that Vc is around Vcc/2 (the operating point is the middle between the supply rails). So, the transistor is properly biased by the NFB mechanism. Here is another viewpoint. You can think of the Vbe threshold as a constant input voltage that is compared with the output voltage of the voltage divider by subtracting in a series manner.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist That is an unusual circuit configuration, of no relevance to the main question. It is not remotely what is going on here. The significant voltage divider is that from +Vcc to Base to Gnd. Feedback is not bias. Your last comment is just nonsense, sorry. It seems there is more than just transistor operation you need to understand.

Comment: Yes, this is the standard "external" biasing. But here, in addition to it, there is another "self-biasing" by the connection between the collector and base (another voltage divider acting as a feedback network). So there are two bias circuits. I have said that one of them can be removed... and, according to me, I would remove the "external" since the NFB biasing is more stable... and more clever. It is widely used in biasing circuits of power amplifiers. And, in my opinion, it is better to persuade our interlocutor with more and more explanations instead of making (offensive) classifications.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Bias is static, that is its whole point. Feedback is dynamic, that is its whole point. You are confusing static bias with dynamic feedback.

Comment: Interesting thoughts... What does biasing mean? Just to add another but constant input voltage (current) to the "true" varying input voltage (current). To bias a BJT, we simply connect a(nother) base resistor to Vcc. But this is, as you said, a "static" biasing that depends on the temperature variations, transistor 'beta', etc. So, let's connect the base resistor to Vc instead to Vcc. What is the difference? As before, a bias current will begin entering the base... and Vbe will approach 0.7 V... but the transistor will begin diverting some current through its collector-emitter junction...

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the indisputable fact that the output voltage cannot be negative, it would be interesting to see what kind of circuit this is. It seems it is not so trivial since we can see a negative feedback inside it.

**Structure.** The upper 10 k resistor connected between the collector and base and the bottom resistor connected between the base and ground form a feedback network (voltage divider) for this *voltage-type negative feedback*. This arrangement resembles a "Vbe voltage multiplier" aka "rubber diode".

Thus the upper biasing resistor connected between Vcc and the base is not so necessary since the transistor is self-biased by the negative feedback and can be removed (unless there are some special reasons to stay there).

The input and output voltages are applied, accordingly, through the 1 k  and 10 k resistors to the base. The two resistors form a summing network widely used in negative feedback systems. So this circuit is equivalent to an op-amp inverting amplifier with R1 = 1 k and R2 = 10 k... and a gain of -R2/R1 = -10. The transistor acts as an inverting "op-amp" with a single-ended inverting  input (the base) where a "virtual ground" with voltage of 0.7 V appears.

**Operation.** Let's consider three typical  cases when the input voltage is *zero*, *positive* and *negative* (the input voltage before the decoupling capacitor is only positive but after the capacitor it becomes bipolar since the capacitor "shifts down" the positive input voltage variations).

*Zero input voltage.* Because of the negative feedback, the transistor adjusts its output voltage so that to set the base voltage about 0.7 V. As a result, the collector voltage becomes Vcc/2… and the transistor is properly biased.

*Positive input voltage.* When the input voltage increases, the base voltage tries to increase as well... but the transistor immediately reacts to this input "intervention". It begins decreasing its collector voltage and restores the equilibrium.

*Negative input voltage.* When the input voltage decreases, the base voltage tries to decrease as well. The transistor immediately reacts to this input "intervention". Now it begins increasing its collector voltage and restores the equilibrium.

**Range.** The input voltage "wiggles" around the ground; the output voltage "swings" between the supply rails.

Comment: Looks like a bog-basic AC amplifier to me. The negative feedback is there to limit the gain to x 10.

Comment: @Guy Inchbald, I have corrected my initial answer. IMO the upper resistor in the center is not necessary and it can be removed.This is my final correct explanation of this weird circuit...